# Delete text only of a specific color from an Excel spreadsheet with text in different colors

Tags: vba, excel

I have a spreadsheet with text in two colors, often in the same cells. I would like to run a macro which deletes only the black text from each cell in which it appears.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Before asking another question, or changing this one, you may want to refer to the [ask] FAQ. To answer your question: you could follow the steps [listed here](http://chandoo.org/forums/topic/can-i-delete-cells-based-on-format) while recording a macro, changing what you need from there. (Found using Google:["excel delete data based on format"](http://www.google.com/search?q=excel+delete+data+based+on+format)) Once that's done, if you run into any specific problems with your code, bring it back here and add those details to this question so we can help you out!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use a macro, why not use the "find and select" tool. Go to "replace". select "options". Select "format" and select the font colour or cell colour option. choose the colour you want to get rid of, leave the "replace with" box blank and click "replace all"

Comment: This should be the selected answer. So simple.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
Sub ForEachCharacterTextColor()
Dim wbk As Workbook
Dim i As Integer
Set wbk = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wbk.Sheets(1)

Dim cell As Range

Cells.Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "@"
Range("A1").Select

On Error GoTo MyExitSub

    With ws
        For Each cell In ws.Range("A1:E2000").Cells
            'cell.Value = "'" & cell.Value
            For i = 1 To Len(cell)
                If cell.Characters(i, 1).Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) Then
                    If Len(cell) > 0 Then
                        cell.Characters(i, 1).Delete
                    End If
                    If Len(cell) > 0 Then
                        i = i - 1
                    End If
                End If
            Next i
        Next cell
    End With


MyExitSub:
    If Err.Number > 0 Then
     MsgBox "Some of your cells are numbers formatted as text. You need to convert them to text completely."
     End
    End If
End Sub
```

Good Luck. - It will work as long as excel doesn't think any of your cells are intended to be numbers.