# Excel VBA trying to match array with wild cards

Tags: excel, vba, match, wildcard, rtf

I currently have a piece of code that I used in a past life...

```
Dim ArrNames

ArrNames = Array("X-Axis", "Y-Axis", "Z-Axis", "Flatness", _
  "Length-X", "Length-Y", "Length-Z", "Length_X", "Length_Y", _
  "Length_Z", "Length", "Angle", "Angle-XY", "Angle-XZ", "Angle-YX", _
  "Angle-YZ", "Angle-ZX", "Angle-ZY", "Radius", "Diameter", "Flatness", _
  "Straightness", "Parallelism", "Perpendicular", "Circularity")

Sheets(2).Range("A:A").Copy Destination:=Sheets(1).Range("A:A", "C:C")

With ActiveSheet
    Lastrow = .UsedRange.Rows(.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row
    For Lrow = Lastrow To 1 Step -1
        With .Cells(Lrow, "C")
            If IsError(Application.Match(.Value, ArrNames, 0)) Then .ClearContents
        End With
    Next Lrow
    For Lrow = Lastrow To 1 Step -1
        With .Cells(Lrow, "A")
            If Not IsError(Application.Match(.Value, ArrNames, 0)) Then .ClearContents
        End With
    Next Lrow
End With
```

So what this does is... it copies a column (column A) from sheet # 2 and pastes the contents into sheet # 1 in two places (column A and column C). The data contains several hundreds of lines of strings like this:

```
(Z): Item (126) / (X) : Item (132)
Circle:P4_EJECTOR_SIDE_OP_10_Locate
Z-axis
X-axis

Point:P8_PAD_PNT
Y-axis

Plane:P8_PAD
Flatness
Parallelism

Circle:P8_EJECTOR_SIDE_DEEP
Z-axis
X-axis
```

Then, I loop through line by line of sheet # 1 column C checking to see if the cell contents match any of the values in my array. If a match is not found, I clear the contents of the cell.

Then, Similarly, I loop through line by line of sheet # 1 column A checking to see if the cell contents match any of the values in my array. However, in this case if a match is found, I clear the contents of the cell (so basically the opposite of what column C is doing).

This is only a part of a much larger animal that automatically imports separate .csv files and compiles the data together for statistical analysis, and it works.

Now I am trying to do a similar thing with .rtf files. The files look like this...

```
(Z): Item (126) / (X) : Item (132)
Circle:P4_EJECTOR_SIDE_OP_10_Locate
Z-axis       -46.435   -46.500    -0.150    +0.150     0.065 ---+*--
X-axis      -116.836  -117.000    -0.150    +0.150     0.164 ---+-->       0.014
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Point:P8_PAD_PNT
Y-axis       -21.611   -21.500    -0.200    +0.200    -0.111 -*-+---
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Plane:P8_PAD
Flatness       0.015     0.200                                  *---
Parallelism    0.078     0.200,FA(Part_Offset_Plane)            +*--
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Circle:P8_EJECTOR_SIDE_DEEP
Z-axis         0.072     0.000    -0.150    +0.150     0.072 ---+*--
X-axis        -0.010     0.000    -0.150    +0.150    -0.010 ---*---
```

So I tried to modify my ArrNames to include wild characters, like this:

ArrNames = Array("---*")

But it isn't working...

I am trying to delete all the "---------------------"

Here is my exact code:

Sub test()

```
Dim Word As New Word.Application
Dim WordDoc As New Word.Document
Dim FilesToOpen
Dim x As Integer
Dim Lrow As Long
Dim Lastrow As Long
Dim ArrNames

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
End With

ArrNames = Array("---*")

FilesToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename _
  (FileFilter:="RTF Files (*.rtf), *.rtf", _
  MultiSelect:=True, Title:="Files to Open")

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

x = 1

Set WordDoc = Word.Documents.Open(Filename:=FilesToOpen(x), ReadOnly:=True)
Word.Selection.WholeStory
Word.Selection.Copy

Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

WordDoc.Close
Word.Quit

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

With ActiveSheet
    Lastrow = .UsedRange.Rows(.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row
    'For Lrow = Lastrow To 1 Step -1
        'With .Cells(Lrow, "A")
            'If IsError(Application.Match(.Value, ArrNames, 0)) Then .ClearContents
        'End With
    'Next Lrow
    For Lrow = Lastrow To 1 Step -1
        With .Cells(Lrow, "A")
            If Not IsError(Application.Match(.Value, ArrNames, 0)) Then .ClearContents
        End With
    Next Lrow
End With

End Sub
```

As you can see I simply copied the loop portion of the code from my previous code and commented out the part I am not currently using.

Comment: Have you looked into the `InStr()` Function? You can use it to check if a string contains a specific character or sequence of characters.

Comment: sounds like a good idea... I may have looked at it months ago when I wrote that portion of code but couldn't figure out how to get it to work... I am very much a novice and just stumbling my way around. I was just now able to get it to work by replacing ".value" in ".match" with "Left(.Value, 3)" and changing the value in my array to "---". But some day I would like to know how to do it without using "left" and instead use the wild card like this "---*"

Comment: So I think I just figured out a super simple way to do this... the data is actually color coded... Instead of using an array of all the stuff I want to delete... can I just simply say delete all blue text? How do I do this? How do I delete all blue text in column A

Comment: phew this question has a lot going on. it would really help if you could trim it to be more concise and address more clearly the problem you're having

Comment: also, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12042161/delete-text-only-of-a-specific-color-from-an-excel-spreadsheet-with-text-in-diff

Comment: You can check the color of a cell with `Range().DisplayFormat.Font.Color`. Figure out which value your blue cells return, then use that as your condition to delete them.

Comment: @XCELLGUY I believe if you used `InStr(1, .Value, "-") = 0`, the statement would be true if there the `InStr` function **couldn't** find a "-". If the function finds the requested value, it returns the location of the first instance of the value within the search string.

Comment: I tried: Sub test2()
    Range("A2").DisplayFormat.Font.Color
End Sub --> but it said invalid use of the property .color